# Cargar datos de un fichero en un diccionario (Python)

Tags: python

antes de nada, desearos Feliz navidad a todos :)

Ahora, la duda...

Tengo un diccionario de usuarios tal que así:

```
# login : [pass, nombre, apellido, ids recomendados, id, si/no admin]
usuarios = {"root": ["1234", "antonio", "fernandez", [], 0, True],
"javpar": ["1234", "javier", "parrales", ["root"], 1, False],
"josper": ["1234", "josé", "pérez", ["root", "javpar"], 2, False]}
```

Lo que necesito es guardar la información en un fichero para posteriormente cargarla de nuevo en el diccionario (cuando se vuelva a ejecutar el programa), de forma que si yo durante una sesión creo dos usuarios, cuando vuelva a entrar, esos dos usuarios estén en el diccionario.

El problema viene al tener listas dentro de listas y tener enteros y booleanos mezclados con cadenas... Mi idea (lo que tengo hecho, vaya) ha sido guardar en el fichero los datos de esta forma:

```
root,['1234', 'antonio', 'fernandez', [], 0, True]
javpar,['1234', 'javier', 'parrales', ['root'], 1, False]
josper,['1234', 'josé', 'pérez', ['root', 'javpar'], 2, False]
```

Pero a partir de aquí, todo lo que se ocurre para cargar los datos, tiene fallos, es decir, que no se me ocurre cómo cargarlos al diccionario de manera coerrecta... Si alguien me echa una mano estaría eternamente agradecido.

Un saludo y que paséis buenas fiestas! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de serializar un objeto `python` es mediante el módulo [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), para guardar el diccionario en primer lugar podríamos hacer:

```
with open('usuarios.pickle', 'wb') as hafndle:
    pickle.dump(usuarios, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

y luego para leerlo:

```
with open('usuarios.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    usuarios = pickle.load(f)
```

La principal ventaja es que no requieres ningún módulo externo, y es una forma muy rápida de serializar los datos, la única eventual contra, es que el archivo tiene un formato binario y no puede ser editado de manera externa como si podrían serlo otros formatos.

Si por el contrario, buscas que la serialización sea legible, lo ideal es usar el módulo [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html), para guardar:

```
with open('usuarios.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(usuarios, f)
```

Y luego para leer:

```
with open('usuarios.json', 'r') as f:
    usuarios = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Hola Patricio! Muchas gracias por contestar. Tengo una duda, a ver si me puede echar otro cable... Yo tengo el diccionario usuarios creado al principio del todo, y debajo la función para cargar los datos, pero cuando dentro de la función hago: usuarios = pickle.load(f), ejecuto la función y no hace nada. En Pycharm me salta el aviso "shadows name 'usuarios' from outer scope". Y no entiendo qué pasa, porque si por ejemplo hago un usuarios.clear() dentro de la función, si funciona, modifico desde la función el diccionario, pero no consigo cargar los datos... Un saludo y muchísimas gracias :).

Comment: ¿que significa que no pasa nada? fundamentalmente el `usuarios = pickle.load(f)` siempre que el archivo hubiera sido correctamente salvado, debería cargarte el diccionario `usuarios` con los datos, si haces un `print(usuarios)` justo luego del `load` que ¿se muestra?

Comment: Significa que si yo hago dentro de la función el usuarios = pickle.load(f), el diccionario se queda igual, no carga los datos. Haciéndolo fuera de la función sí funciona, pero cuando intento hacerlo en una función, nada. Pero bueno, estuve probando ayer a ver cómo lo solucionaba y ya lo tengo, lo que hago es un return pickle.load(f) y se lo asigno al diccionario, de esa forma sí lo consigo modificar. Un saludo Patricio y muchísimas gracias por todo :), que pases felices fiestas! :D

Comment: Ok, te entiendo, el problema es que dentro de la función `usuarios` es una variable local, es decir fuera de la función lo que ves es otro objeto `usuarios` distinto. Lo que estás haciendo, retornar el objeto, es lo adecuado. Saludos.